# Percentage of sales

Tags: sql

I'm trying to calculate the quantity sold to a specific customer per item x our total sales per item. I want to see if there's any product that this customer has a large share in our total sales.

I want to group it by date, item number and warehouse code.

For some reason the values are not right. Can someone please take a look and see if there's any problem with the query below? Appreciate your help!

```
    SELECT 
DISTINCT 
tb1."ItemCode"
,tb1."ItemName"
, tb2."Quantity" as "Quantity"
, tb2."LineTotal" as "Revenue"
, tb2."AvgPrice" as "Average Sale Price"
, tb3."Quantity" as "Specific customer Quantity"
, tb3."LineTotal" as "Specific customer Revenue"
, tb3."AvgPrice" as "Specific customer Avg Sale Price"
,tb3."Date" as "Date"
,tb2."Warehouse" as "Warehouse"
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT T0."ItemCode", "ItemName" FROM "xx" T0
) tb1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
SELECT
    DISTINCT T1."ItemCode" as "ItemCode"
    , SUM(T1."Quantity") as "Quantity"
    , SUM(T1."LineTotal") as "LineTotal"
    , AVG(T1."PriceBefDi") as "AvgPrice
,T1."DocDate" as "Date"
,T1."WhsCode" as "Warehouse"
FROM "xx2"T1 INNER JOIN "xx3"T0 ON T0."DocEntry"=T1."DocEntry"
        WHERE T0."CANCELED" = 'N'
GROUP BY T1."ItemCode", T1."DocDate", T1."WhsCode"
    ) tb2
ON tb1."ItemCode" = tb2."ItemCode"
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
SELECT
    DISTINCT T1."ItemCode" as "ItemCode"
    , SUM(T1."Quantity") as "Quantity"
    , SUM(T1."LineTotal") as "LineTotal"
    , AVG(T1."PriceBefDi") as "AvgPrice"
 ,T1."DocDate" as "Date"
,T1."WhsCode"
FROM "xx2"T1 INNER JOIN "xx3"T0 ON T0."DocEntry"=T1."DocEntry"
        WHERE T0."CANCELED" = 'N'
    AND T0."CardCode" = 'Specific Customer'
        GROUP BY T1."ItemCode", T1."DocDate", T1."WhsCode") tb3 ON tb1."ItemCode" = tb3."ItemCode"
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what do you mean by not right?  What is your expected output?  What is your current output?  More info needed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @Mariana Marques.  Please see Eric's comment.  Some more information will help others provide you a solution.